# Dynamic SQL and RAISERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, raiserror

I have 5 dynamic SQL inserts running within a `TRY CATCH` however the `CATCH` block is not letting the parent stored procedure that runs this code know its may have failed. I need to add a `RAISERROR` after each dynamic SQL to flag if one errors.

Each dSQL ends with

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @param_definition, @param
```

Do I call the `RAISERROR` after each or do I just need one in the `CATCH`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So long as the dynamic queries don't contain any TRY/CATCH, then [THROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql)ing (or RAISERROR before SQL 2012) in the CATCH is sufficient.  Like

```
begin try
  . . .
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @param_definition, @param
  . . .
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @param_definition, @param
  . . .
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @param_definition, @param
end try
begin catch 
  throw
end catch
```